# Add html ID to content field

Tags: 7, nodes

When I create the content (specific to the content, not to the content type), I want to type in an optional ID, that would be set on the html element.

Is there a module for this?

Comment: What is the end result of this?  Are you actually wanting user input to dictate the 'id=' attribute of an html object?  If so, due to any number of reasons, this is just opening yourself up to trouble.

Comment: @Jimajamma Well, making it optional, and probably using a prefix, I dont see many problems with it. 
I just want to be able to select this particular field with javascript easily. It's important that the the id is set on the node - not the content type.

Comment: Just as long as things are set up such that you can never have a duplicate, there is no problem.  Making such a claim is easier said than done.  If anything, making it id='$prefix-$nid-$vid' or something would make it there and obviate the need for it being optional.

Comment: @Jimajamma Collisions would not be an issue either - this is used only in a few pages, managed by one administrator...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Drupal 6, you can theme cck fields by copying content-field.tpl.php from the CCK module's includes directory to your theme directory and then creating a content-field-FIELDNAME.tpl.php to customize the look of that individual field.  Or, if you want to wrap every field with a uniquely id'ed div, you could edit your copy of content-field.tpl.php and add:

```
<div id="<?php print $field_name_css . '-' . $node->nid; ?>">

-- php code between the check if the field isn't empty --

</div>
```

to the template, or around whatever portion in it you needed.  Just be careful with multiple field items, their ids would need a -$delta added to them if you put this inside the code of the template instead of wrapping it entirely, or adding the id= to the first div, etc.  If you want to id it with a user supplied field, you can grab that from the $node given, eg

```
$node->field_my_optional_id[0]['value']
```

but you have to sanitize it.

Now, I know you said Drupal 7, and I am sure it's subtly different there, but this should put you on the right path.  Hope it helps!

UPDATE/EDIT:  It's field.tpl.php from the system module field's theme directory in D7.